# Experience error messages in C# Blackjack Code

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, formatting

I'm a beginner to C#, having previously used Python. I've been programming this Blackjack code and I'm experiencing a few errors. I can't seem to solve them and I think it is down to missing a brackets or something somewhere in the code as it worked fine before.

I've made efforts to try and figure it out for myself but I just can't. Getting the hang of C# formatting is a real change from Python.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Blackjack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        // Creating array
        string[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
        string[] cards = new string[13];
        cards[0] = "A";
        cards[1] = "2";
        cards[2] = "3";
        cards[3] = "4";
        cards[4] = "5";
        cards[5] = "6";
        cards[6] = "7";
        cards[7] = "8";
        cards[8] = "9";
        cards[9] = "10";
        cards[10] = "J";
        cards[11] = "Q";
        cards[12] = "K";
        int dealer_total = 0;
        int player_total = 0;
        int blackjack = 21;
        // Dealing 2 player cards, then calculating and outputting card value
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
            int suit = r.Next(0, 4);
            int card = r.Next(0, 13);
            string suit_name = suits[suit];
            string card_name = cards[card];
            string full_name = card_name + " of " + suit_name;
            Console.WriteLine(full_name);
            int cardValue = getcardvalue(card_name);
            player_total = player_total + cardValue;
            Console.WriteLine("You have a total of " + player_total); // Prints player's card value
            }
        bool hit = true;
        while (hit)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to stick or hit?");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input.ToLower() == "stick")
                    {
                hit = false;
                // Dealing dealer cards
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                    int suit = r.Next(0, 4);
                    int card = r.Next(0, 13);
                    string suit_name = suits[suit];
                    string card_name = cards[card];
                    string full_name = card_name + " of " + suit_name;
                    int cardValue = getcardvalue(card_name);
                    dealer_total = dealer_total + cardValue;
                    Console.WriteLine("Dealer has a total of " + dealer_total);
                    if (dealer_total > player_total)
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Dealer wins, you lose.");
                        }
                    else if ((player total) > (dealer_total))
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine("You win!");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Dealer total matches your total, draw.");
                    }
                }

            // if player chooses to hit, another card is drawn
        　
            else if (input.ToLower() == "hit")
            {
            int suit = r.Next(0, 4);
            int card = r.Next(0, 13);
            string suit_name = suits[suit];
            string card_name = cards[card];
            string full_name = card_name + " of " + suit_name;
            Console.WriteLine(full_name);
            int cardValue = getcardvalue(card_name);
            player_total = player_total + cardValue;
            Console.WriteLine("You have a total of " + player_total);
                if (player_total > 21)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("You are bust; you lose.");
                hit = false;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid response. Please choose either stick or hit.");
            // Outputs an error message if anything else is input
            }
            }
                }
        private static int getcardvalue(string card_name)
        {
        int card_value = 0;
        if (card_name == "A") // ie if the card is an Ace
        {
        card_value = 11;
        }
        else if (card_name == "K" || card_name == "Q" || card_name == "J") // if the card is a face card
        {
        card_value = 10;
        }
        else
        {
        card_value = int.Parse(card_name); //if the card is any other card, then it is worth its pip value
        }
        return card_value;
    }
}
}
```

I'm receiving the following errors:

```
main.cs(67,22): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `total'
main.cs(67,27): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
main.cs(67,27): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)'
main.cs(67,45): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `;' or `}'
main.cs(71,5): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `else'
main.cs(85,4): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `else'
main.cs(110,3): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `private'
main.cs(110,34): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `('
```

Comment: A small suggestion in addition to the answers... You can shorten your array initialization like this `string[] cards = new string[13]{ "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the same code without the errors.

Changes:

Line 68: `player total` changed to `player_total`

Line 77: Added closing bracket for `if`, required before the `else` block

What editor/IDE are you using? These errors would be quite easy to spot in an IDE such as visual studio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Blackjack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creating array
            string[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
            string[] cards = new string[13];
            cards[0] = "A";
            cards[1] = "2";
            cards[2] = "3";
            cards[3] = "4";
            cards[4] = "5";
            cards[5] = "6";
            cards[6] = "7";
            cards[7] = "8";
            cards[8] = "9";
            cards[9] = "10";
            cards[10] = "J";
            cards[11] = "Q";
            cards[12] = "K";
            int dealer_total = 0;
            int player_total = 0;
            int blackjack = 21;
            // Dealing 2 player cards, then calculating and outputting card value
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                int suit = r.Next(0, 4);
                int card = r.Next(0, 13);
                string suit_name = suits[suit];
                string card_name = cards[card];
                string full_name = card_name + " of " + suit_name;
                Console.WriteLine(full_name);
                int cardValue = getcardvalue(card_name);
                player_total = player_total + cardValue;
                Console.WriteLine("You have a total of " + player_total); // Prints player's card value
            }
            bool hit = true;
            while (hit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to stick or hit?");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input.ToLower() == "stick")
                {
                    hit = false;
                    // Dealing dealer cards
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        int suit = r.Next(0, 4);
                        int card = r.Next(0, 13);
                        string suit_name = suits[suit];
                        string card_name = cards[card];
                        string full_name = card_name + " of " + suit_name;
                        int cardValue = getcardvalue(card_name);
                        dealer_total = dealer_total + cardValue;
                        Console.WriteLine("Dealer has a total of " + dealer_total);
                        if (dealer_total > player_total)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Dealer wins, you lose.");
                        }
                        else if ((player_total) > (dealer_total))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You win!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Dealer total matches your total, draw.");
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if player chooses to hit, another card is drawn

                else if (input.ToLower() == "hit")
                {
                    int suit = r.Next(0, 4);
                    int card = r.Next(0, 13);
                    string suit_name = suits[suit];
                    string card_name = cards[card];
                    string full_name = card_name + " of " + suit_name;
                    Console.WriteLine(full_name);
                    int cardValue = getcardvalue(card_name);
                    player_total = player_total + cardValue;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have a total of " + player_total);
                    if (player_total > 21)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You are bust; you lose.");
                        hit = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid response. Please choose either stick or hit.");
                    // Outputs an error message if anything else is input
                }
            }
        }
        private static int getcardvalue(string card_name)
        {
            int card_value = 0;
            if (card_name == "A") // ie if the card is an Ace
            {
                card_value = 11;
            }
            else if (card_name == "K" || card_name == "Q" || card_name == "J") // if the card is a face card
            {
                card_value = 10;
            }
            else
            {
                card_value = int.Parse(card_name); //if the card is any other card, then it is worth its pip value
            }
            return card_value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a REPL at the moment as I'm away from my normal work computer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a higher-level suggestion I hope you don't mind: don't try to force formatting - whatever development environment you're using (VisualStudio, something else) - let *it* control your braces.

Here's why - this is what your code looks like if you let VisualStudio do the formatting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    ... bunch of lines of code at this indenting level
}
else if (input.ToLower() == "hit")
```

... and it becomes obvious: something got missed in terms of brackets, because you can't end a For-Loop with an Else-If clause.  *Probably* another bracket is missing, to exit out of that for() loop, likely after the dealer_total line.

It becomes a *lot* harder to spot errors like that if you're doing your indenting, because it's easy to mess up your indenting.  As an example, from your code:

```
            if (input.ToLower() == "stick")
                {
            hit = false;
            // Dealing dealer cards
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

... see the issue?  You didn't indent the 'hit = false;' lines from that point onward.

Whatever your IDE is, just let it take care of formatting (and if you don't have an IDE, at least get VisualStudio community, which is free.)  It'll save you quite a bit of headaches.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll take it on board